# Flash AS3 XML Listener infinite trigger

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to read a XML file and display its content in a simple list component or at the console.
The problem is that the event listener is triggered in an infinite loop.

**The code:**

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("/songs/songs.xml"));

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.*);
}
```

**The xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Songs>
    <Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
    <Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
</Songs>
```

**The output:**

`<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
<Song>Kalimba.mp3</Song>
<Song>Sleep Away.mp3</Song>
....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, is this just on the timeline of the IDE?  If so, do you need to add a `stop()`?

Secondly, you could remove the listener from the loader as soon as the `COMPLETE` event comes out.

```
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.*);
}
```

Comment: I use only one keyframe on timeline and after adding stop() it worked, lol.Thanks a lot !